# What is the most efficient way to return a simple (but large) array from a function in classic asp?

Tags: arrays, function, asp-classic

I am using a classic asp function that returns an array, like this:

```
        function myArray()
            dim tmpArray(2) 
            tmpArray(0) = "abc"
            tmpArray(1) = "xyz"
            tmpArray(2) = "bob"
            myArray = tmpArray
        end function
```

I'd like to know if there's any benefit to reconstructing it like this instead, and bypassing the tmpArray variable?

```
        function myArray()
            myArray(0) = "abc"
            myArray(1) = "xyz"
            myArray(2) = "bob"
        end function
```

I know performance isn't much of an issue on something simple like this... however in the deployed code we might be using a whole lot of these arrays, each containing hundreds of items.

---

**Bonus question:**
In the second example, how would I go about dimming the array size or would it have to be dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing a test (for the record, I used VBA), your second method produced a stack overflow error because **myArray(0) = "abc"** would just just recursively call the **myArray()** function.

So I tried another test. Instead of the second function returning an array, I had it set an array that was declared in a higher scope, so I didn't have to pass any arrays.

I used 1,000 element arrays, and called each function 10,000 times. For your first function, it took 8 seconds, for the second, it took 2 seconds.

Good luck

Comment: Wow, cool, then that's the way we'll be doing it. I feel lazy for not testing myself now. Thanks ever so.

Comment: @Tom, it may help to see the code you used to test. I have a feeling that passing the array using a [`ByRef`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) parameter would have similar performance as using global variables.

Comment: @Cheran, sorry, already deleted. Depending on where it's called from, a ByRef variable probably would be just as fast.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see the rest of your code for context, I am not 100% sure about my suggestion but will say it, in case it gives you ideas.
There are various built in functions that might serve your purposes, depending on where your data is coming from.
If you have a string like "frank, sue, ted, john" then:
- Have you looked into the built in Split() function?
Or if your data is in a database table, then:
- Have you looked into the built in GetRows() function?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, good call. We've already accessed the data using GetRows(), but now we're looking for an efficient way to pass a single one of these rows through for processing by another function.  The dealbreaker is that it we don't know the number of columns in advance.  So now we just iterate through the columns (using ubound) and create a new 1D array from the values of each row. Doesn't feel very elegant, but it works.